# Linking remote files issue

Tags: php, javascript, html, content-type

I am placing href links to remote files for download simple as this with ajax:

```
<a href="http://remotesite.com/filename.flv">Link</a>
```

but it opens in new window and cuts off http:// and returns not found error, although if i refresh the page it will start downloading the file.

Maybe i could specify the content type and pass with header somehow but i dont want to pass the file through my server, it should download it from remote link.

Hope i could explain well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

sounds like the remote site has some protection against hot linking.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that the link is correct? Try testing it externally first using an online flash player such as http://www.flvplayeronline.com/ . If the video plays then as @EvilSpaceHamster stated it could be a permissions issue on the server.  I noticed you stated download? Is this a requirement or do you just want to grant the user access to view the file?

Comment: The files are accessible and it just returns not found page for the first time but page refresh starts the download. I just want user to download it. I tried the following way and in that case it works but with download limit from my server which i really dont want to change or pass the file through my server.
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$name}");
readfile($file);